# Passing dropdown data which is gatherd from a mysql table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need a script that loads data form mysql and show on a drop down list. From there, I need to pass the selected data to another page.
I have done the first step. I am now able to load data from mysql table and to show them on a drop down menu. The exact is given bellow.

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$result= mysql_query("SELECT folder_name FROM folders");

echo '<select name="directory">'; // Open your drop down box

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   //echo "<option>" . $row['folder_name'] . "</option>";
      echo '<option value="'.$row['folder_name'].'">'.$row['folder_name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';// Close your drop down box
?>
```

Now I need help to pass the selected data to another page. Any suggestion please?

Comment: Do you use javascript? Do you want to load the other page on change of that select or press a button and then perform the redirect ?

Comment: What trigger do you want to use to send the data? When the drop-down changes? When a form is submitted? You need to be specific.

Comment: @mallix: no, no javascrip. just the php. yes, i want to load the action page by clicking a button

Comment: @hohner: dropdown only changes when I refresh the page. and after selecting a data from the dropdown, I want it to pass just like what we do in simple html from with php POST method.

Comment: Ok I created an example using js. Now noticed that you don t want js..

Comment: Thank you all for your helping effort :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me consider the `form` is posted to `page2.php` from `page1.php`

**page1.php**

```
<form method="post" action="page2.php">
        //your dropdown code here
        <?php
              include("config.php");
              $result= mysql_query("SELECT folder_name FROM folders");

              $str = '';   
              $str .= '<select name="directory">'; // Open your drop down box

              while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
              $str .= '<option    value="'.$row['folder_name'].'">'.$row['folder_name'].'</option>';
              }
              $str .= '</select>';// Close your drop down box

              echo $str;
         ?>

   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

in page2.php you can access the `dropdown` selected value as

```
$selVal = '';
if(isset($_POST['directory']))
{
    $selVal = $_POST['directory'];
}
```

Comment: Many thanks DON. your suggestion worked! You've saved my time and effort. Thank you very much for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

create a javascript function to handle the redirect with the folder name data:

```
function changePage(folder){
 window.location.href= 'http://www.yourdomain.com/page2.php?folder=' + folder;
}
```

onchange option, trigger changePage javascript function with folder name as input:

```
include("config.php");
$result= mysql_query("SELECT folder_name FROM folders");

echo '<select name="directory">'; // Open your drop down box

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo '<option value="'.$row['folder_name'].'" onchange="changePage(\''.$row['folder_name'].'\')">'.$row['folder_name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';// Close your drop down box
```

page2.php

```
$folder_name = strip_tags($_GET['folder']);
```